# Keep selected cell on heavily reloadRowsAtIndexPaths UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, cell

In one of the views there is a UITableView which is getting updated rather often.
Tracking the changes are done in a classic way using "reloadRowsAtIndexPaths"

```
-(void)refreshCells:(NSArray *)changedCells
{
    NSLog(@"refreshCells %i",[changedCells count]);
    [TableView beginUpdates];
    [TableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:changedCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [TableView endUpdates];
}
```

Question: How can I preserve the user's last selected Cell. the cell position may change after each update refreshCells?

Comment: Afaik reloadRowsAtIndexPaths just calls the delegates cellForRowAtIndexPath for each index path in 'changedCells' so the number of cells remains the same, therefor the index paths remain the same. If of course for some reason you change the order of how they are returned by cellForRowAtIndexPath, only you can know where the selected cell went^^

Comment: I'm having this problem too. I'm using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to reload one cell. Why does it deselect that cell? That seems like a bug with the iOS SDK. Otherwise, the method should be called: `reloadAndDeselectRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can save the current selection with

```
NSIndexPath *selectedRow = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

before the reload and select it again with

```
if (selectedRow) {
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedRow animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

after the reload. The cell position does not change unless you call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` or `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:`.

Comment: setting the animated property to NO will not let user to see the deselection and selection step. Hence, user will not notice that row was deselected while reloading the cell.

Comment: You can insert `&& ![self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` after `if (selectedRow` if you only want to select the cell if it was unselected. But, I'd leave it out if you're using `animated:NO` and `scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone` because with those arguments, it won't make a difference.