# why is didDeselectRowAtIndexPath not called

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath** is called, but **didDeselectRowAtIndexPath** not called. I don't why. I searched online. Many similar questions,but I don't find answer.

This is my tableview

```
//tableView
    let tempTableView = UITableView()
    tempTableView.delegate = self
    tempTableView.dataSource = self
    tempTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(tempTableView)
    self.tableView = tempTableView
```

This is the delegate

```
 //MARK: UITableViewDelegate
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   self.cayegoryArray[indexPath.row].isSelected = true
   self.tableView?.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.cayegoryArray[indexPath.row].isSelected = false
    self.tableView?.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
}
```

This is cell.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.selectionStyle = .Default

    setInterface()
    setLayout()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: "tableView(_:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:) will only be called after another cell is selected."

Comment: Are you sure that "didDeselect..." isn't called? Or is it called and the tableView isn't reloading? 
Two things: Add a pint() to into "didDeselect..." to be sure that it isn't called and the other thing: Be sure that the cell was selected.

Comment: @FattiKhan When I second tap different cell it is called.

Comment: @rose: That's the desired behaviour, when a cell is deselected that time the didDeselect method will be called. When you first tap on a cell, there is no cell previously selected (so didDeselect won't be called). When you tap on another cell, that time there is a previously selected cell and the method will be called.

Comment: @Godlike I am sure It is not called

Comment: @MidhunMP I know didDeselect won't be called when I first tap on a cell. But when I tap on anorher cell, it alse isn't called.

Comment: @rose Oh you are right, sry. You are reloading your Row and because of this, the row shouldn't be selected anymore... Have a look: (To keep it selected) http://stackoverflow.com/a/13046014/4906484

Comment: Ok good i'm sure something is wrong

Comment: checkout my solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/44097559/1600061

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that    `self.tableView?.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)` causes the cell to be reloaded and hence it is never deselected.

You can fix these by adding         `self.tableView?.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)` after you reload the cells

i.e.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   self.cayegoryArray[indexPath.row].isSelected = true
   self.tableView?.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
   self.tableView?.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
}
```